# YamlDotNet - Parse properties in a Dictionary

Tags: c#, yaml, yamldotnet

I would like to parse the following YAML

```
urls:
   who: /fr-fr/who-we-are
   test: /fr-fr/test

targetDirectory: d:\temp
```

Into the following structure:

```
public class UserConfig 
{ 
    public Dictionary<string, string> Urls { get; set; } 
    public string TargetDirectory { get; set; } 
}
```

I try to serialize it with:

```
var deserializer = new DeserializerBuilder() 
                      .WithNamingConvention(new CamelCaseNamingConvention())
                      .Build();
```

But I always obtains the following error: (Line: 2, Col: 1, Idx: 8) - (Line: 2, Col: 2, Idx: 9): Expected 'MappingStart', got 'SequenceStart' (at Line: 2, Col: 1, Idx: 8).

Is this library able to support a mapping of key values? If yes how can I do that?

EDIT:

This YAML give me the exact same result:

```
urls: 
- who: /fr-fr/qui-sommes-nous?sc_site=schmidttest
- fabricantfrancais: /fr-fr/avantages-cuisinella/1er-fabricant-francais

targetDirectory: d:\temp
```

Regards,
Benjamin V.

Comment: Are you sure you parse the correct YAML? The error message suggests there is a sequence in your YAML at line 2, while there evidently is none in your YAML.

Comment: Yes I have tried with this syntax but also with the other one I have added in the message and the message is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Hello I have received an answer from the github manager: https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/issues/328

> That's because your YAML document is a sequence of mappings, instead of a mapping. That would map to a List>. If you can control the structure of your YAML document, you should change it to:
>
> urls: 
>     who: /fr-fr/who-we-are
>     test: /fr-fr/test
>
> targetDirectory: d:\temp\
>   otherwise, you will need to implement a class that implements ICollection and use that type as the Urls property.

Thank you for your help!